# What is a headless command line application?

Tags: node.js, unix, command-line-tool

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166617/what-does-it-mean-for-electron-to-combine-node-js-and-chromium-contexts/38166866#38166866) that `Node.js` is a "headless command line application" how is this different from a regular command line tool/app like `cp` or `git`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Headless** only means that it can be run without **a GUI**.
So every command line application is **headless.**

Comment: Perhaps more informatively the term is typically applied when other similar applications do require a GUI. So a headless browser, for example, fetches and reders web pages, but does not attempt to display the rendered page interactively. I believe the "head" originally referred to the display monitor, although the lack of other interactive I/O devices is also required in modern use.